# How do I control input behavior over many input elements with different name attributes?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

My JavaScript skills are a bit green, but I am trying to improve the following:

I am currently using a script to effect a single input element in a form by the input name attribute:

HTML:

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" 
     id="floatingInputGrid" 
     name="hoursstagingbudget" value="0" >
<label for="floatingInputGrid">Hours Staging Budget</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
var nameElement = document.forms.inputform.hoursstagingbudget

  function nameFocus(e) {
    var element = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
    if ( element.value == "0" )
      element.value = "";
  }

  function nameBlur(e) {
    var element = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
    if ( element.value === "" )
      element.value = "0";
  }
  
  if ( nameElement.addEventListener ) {
    nameElement.addEventListener("focus", nameFocus, false);
    nameElement.addEventListener("blur", nameBlur, false);
  } else if ( nameElement.attachEvent ) {
    nameElement.attachEvent("onfocus", nameFocus);
    nameElement.attachEvent("onblur", nameBlur);
  }
```

I want all the number type inputs to behave this way - I'm using document.form...is there a 'type' method or just the 'name' method to use this?

If not, I was thinking I would use an array of the input names, but I'm not having much luck applying that idea either.

Looking for the smartest way to approach this and expand beyond the one named input in the best DRY approach possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use DOM (Document Object Model) to get all inputs and attach the event listener (using `document.forms` etc. isn't recommended) :

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("yourformidhere").getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   var currentElement = inputs[i];
   if(currentElement.addEventListener) {...};
   else if (currentElement.attachEvent) {...};
}
```

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) on how to use DOM if you're interested

Comment: Thanks for this! Works like I needed. Broke me out of my tunnel vision!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would probably be to use `document.querySelectorAll` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)). This will return you a list (not an array) of all the elements that match the css selector you pass in. Assuming all your inputs have the `class="form-control"` this code should do what you described.

```
  const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
  for(let i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){
      if ( nameElement.addEventListener ) {
          inputElements[i].addEventListener("focus", nameFocus, false);
          inputElements[i].addEventListener("blur", nameBlur, false);
      } else if ( nameElement.attachEvent ) {
          inputElements[i].attachEvent("onfocus", nameFocus);
          inputElements[i].attachEvent("onblur", nameBlur);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in my case I needed this only for "number" type inputs and this is the eventual solution that worked (extending PhoenixXKN's answer a bit):

```
var inputs=document.getElementById("inputform").getElementsByTagName("input");

  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'number') {
      var currentElement = inputs[i];
      if(currentElement.addEventListener) {...}
      else if (currentElement.attachEvent) {...};
    }    
  }
```